# Best way to deal with passing data to a widget for the purposes of shortening a complex layout in Flutter / dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

### Background

I'm on day #3 of flutter, so bear with me.  I know next to nothing

### My Problem

I have a screen layout that is super complex with layers and layers of nested children.

Its become totally unreadable.  Many of the items are tabbed so far to the right I am constantly scrolling left and right, making editing nearly impossible at this point.

### My Solution

I want to break it all up into smaller pieces so I decided to make smaller widgets as so:

```
Widget sectionPost = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
  child: Text(
    'Some text',
    softWrap: true,
  ),
);
```

Which I then include into my main layout as follows:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:6.0,horizontal:10.0),
          child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
              ),
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              elevation:0,
              child: sectionPost
          )
      )
```

### My Question

This seems to be working *OK* (although its still tedious to find all the parts).
Some of my data is in the form of variables which are passed into my main layout.  My main layout is a Class / StatelessWidget with data fed into it from a JSON call.  One of these variables is `map`

```
map['author'];
```

The variable `map['author']` works just fine in my main layout Class, but when I've tried to break it up into smaller chunks via smaller widgets the variable is not recognized: `Undefined name 'map'`.

Is there an easy way to pass along these variables to my smaller bite-sized widgets for the purposes of constructing my larger layout?

### Alternatives

As mentioned, I'm on day #3 of flutter, so if I'm approaching this problem totally incorrectly: I'm all ears to a different method of dealing with my underlying problem of a massive layout with unreadable nested code

Comment: One thing it wasn't clear for me: where do you want do use `map['author']`? For example, do you want to replace `'Some text'` in the `sectionPost` variable with `map['author']`? Do you want to display these widgets in a list where each widget contains a author name? Or is there only one author name to be displayed in a single widget?

Comment: @enzo Correct, I'd like to replace `Some text` with `map['author']`.  In reality it will be way more complex with multiple variables passed, but essentially I need to use the variable in the smaller bite size widgets and have that final text or layout returned back to the main Class. This is all part of a larger list view which is iterating and rebuilding a new list item based on the Json data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `StatelessWidget` where you receive the author name as parameter:

```dart
class SectionPost extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;

  const SectionPost(this.name);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Text(name, softWrap: true),
    );
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to access more fields besides the author name, you can pass the map *per se*.

```dart
class SectionPost extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> map;

  const SectionPost(this.map);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Text(map['author'], softWrap: true),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like that in your main code:

```dart
final Map<String, dynamic> map = /* ... */;

Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:6.0,horizontal:10.0),
  child: Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
    ),
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    elevation:0,
    child: SectionPost(map['author']) // or SectionPost(map) if you chose the second approach
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  You have been saving me for 2 days now :)